# form elements not working on modal

Tags: html

I am using the following code to display a form inside of a modal window:

```
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
<form id="modal_feedback" method="POST" action="#" accept-charset="UTF-8">    
<div class="left">
<div class="row">
<div class="inleft">*First Name</div>
<div class="inright"><input type="text" name="fname" required></div>
</div>
<div class="row">    
<div class="inleft">*Last Name</div>
<div class="inright"><label><input type="text" name="lname" required></label></div>
</div>
<div class="row">    
<div class="inleft">Company</div>
<div class="inright"><input type="text" name="company" ></div>
</div>                    
<div class="row">    
<div class="inleft">Website</div>
<div class="inright"><input type="text" name="website" ></div>
</div> 
</form>
</div>
```

Here is my problem: Only the first form element is allowing input. The rest do not allow anyone to enter any information in them, yet they are exactly the same as the first sans the name of course.

Any idea as to what might be causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please close that input tag. May be that is not the problem, but just check

Comment: @vipincp html5 inputs don't need closing. Assuming this is html5 by the required attribute

Comment: Since you're using bog-standard HTML, it's probably not your markup. You can verify this by pasting your HTML code into a standalone page or jsfiddle. There's likely a script--possibly associated with the code that displays your modal--that is causing an issue.